# cannot import name 'load_dotenv' from 'dotenv' with django docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I try to dockerize django.

So I have this Docker file:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8000
# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add linux-headers postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt . 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
# copy project
COPY . .
# run entrypoint.sh

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

and Docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python ./manage.py migrate &&      
             python ./manage.py runserver 0:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env

volumes:
  dev-static-data:
```

Part of settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from os import environ
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

this works fine. when I do a

and my requirements.txt looks like:

```
python manage.py runserver  8080
```

The app runs.

requirements.txt:

```
Django>=4.0.4
djangorestframework>=3.13.1
psycopg2>=2.9.3
drf-spectacular>=0.22.1
Pillow>=9.1.0
drf-yasg==1.20.0 
django-cors-headers==3.10.1
django-dotenv
http://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/archive/uwsgi-2.0.zip
```

I can build the docker container. But I can't run it.

If I do a docker-compose up. I get this error:"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
dwl_backend-app-1  |   File "/usr/src/app/./manage.py", line 5, in <module>
dwl_backend-app-1  |     from DierenWelzijn.settings import base
dwl_backend-app-1  |   File "/usr/src/app/DierenWelzijn/settings/base.py", line 15, in <module>
dwl_backend-app-1  |     from dotenv import load_dotenv
dwl_backend-app-1  | ImportError: cannot import name 'load_dotenv' from 'dotenv' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dotenv.py)
```

if I do a pip freeze I see the package django-dotenv installed:

```
Django==4.1.6
django-allauth==0.52.0
django-cors-headers==3.13.0
django-dotenv==1.4.2
```

Question: how to run the docker django container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Regarding the problem

It looks like there's a confusion with the import method for `django-dotenv` and `python-dotenv`.

1. `django-dotenv` uses:

   ```py
   import dotenv
   dotenv.read_dotenv()
   ```
2. `python-dotenv` (a more general library not specifically for Django, but can be used with it) uses:

   ```py
   from dotenv import load_dotenv
   load_dotenv()
   ```

If you're using `django-dotenv`, make sure you have the correct import. If you've shifted to `python-dotenv`, then you should be using the second method.

To clarify your situation:

1. Check which library you have on your local machine and docker:

   ```
   pip freeze | grep dotenv
   ```
2. If you've installed `django-dotenv`, use:

   ```py
   import dotenv
   dotenv.read_dotenv()
   ```
3. If you've installed `python-dotenv`, use:

   ```py
   from dotenv import load_dotenv
   load_dotenv()
   ```

Regarding Docker, when you're running Django inside a Docker container, the `.env` file needs to be present within the container. If you're using Docker Compose, ensure that the `.env` file is in the correct location or that your Docker configuration is set up to copy the `.env` file into the container during the build or runtime.

## More

I see `django-environ` and `django-dotenv` in your Django project.

You can use both, but they serve similar purposes and might be redundant in most cases. Let's break down what each does:

1. **django-dotenv**:

   - Loads environment variables from a `.env` file.
   - Mainly used to populate the `os.environ` dictionary with the variables defined in a `.env` file.
2. **django-environ**:

   - Also provides support for reading from a `.env` file.
   - Extends the functionality with a more sophisticated system to convert environment variables to Python objects. It provides tools for parsing database URLs, cache URLs, lists, and more.

Given their functionalities:

- If you only need to load environment variables from a `.env` file, then `django-dotenv` is enough.
- If you need advanced parsing of environment variables or the extra features provided by `django-environ`, then you might choose it.

But if you decide to use both:

1. Use `django-dotenv` to load the `.env` file.
2. Use `django-environ` to perform the parsing of the environment variables and cast them into the desired Python types.

Here's an example of how you could use both in a Django project:

1. In your Django project's `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` files, use `django-dotenv` to load the `.env` file:

   ```py
   # manage.py or wsgi.py

   import dotenv
   dotenv.read_dotenv()
   ```
2. In your `settings.py`, use `django-environ` to parse those variables:

   ```py
   # settings.py

   import environ

   env = environ.Env()
   DATABASES = {
       'default': env.db(),
   }

   SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
   ```

Remember that having two packages for similar tasks might be confusing for someone else reading your code or for future you. If one package satisfies all your needs, it's generally cleaner to stick with one.

Comment: Oh, I've got it, It simplier... I will add the update to my answer

Comment: already updated

Comment: Try to `docker-compose build --no-cache`. Then check Dockerfile: Ensure you're copying the requirements.txt to the Docker container and installing the packages,